# R plot_ly row or dataframe in PowerBI custom visuals

Tags: r, dataframe, powerbi, plotly, powerbi-datasource

I am following: http://radacad.com/create-custom-visual-with-r-and-json-part3

Here it is mentioned that with below R code, we can plot the chart:

```
Values<-data.frame(X,Y,Legend,Row,Column)

g=ggplot(Values, aes(x=X, y=Y,colour = Legend))
```

I am using similar implementations.

**Below code renders blank chart with only axis:**

```
Values <- data.frame(mpg_test, cyl_test)
p <- plot_ly(Values,
  x = ~mpg_test,
  y = ~cyl_test,
  name = "SF Zoo",
  type = "bar"
)
```

**Empty chart**
[image]
**Below code also renders empty chart:**

```
Values <- data.frame(mpg_test, cyl_test)
p <- plot_ly(Values,
  x = mpg_test,
  y = cyl_test,
  name = "SF Zoo",
  type = "bar"
)
```

**Below code renders correct chart:**

```
Values <- data.frame(mpg_test, cyl_test)
p <- plot_ly(Values,
  x = ~mpg_test[1:nrow(Values), ], 
  y = ~cyl_test[1:nrow(Values), ],
  name = "SF Zoo",
  type = "bar"
)
```

**Correct chart:**

[image]
My doubt is, as per the tutorial I must get columns in `mpg_test` and `cyl_test`, then why I am getting something like `dataframe` in here.
Does, plotly handles things differently with the usage of `~` ?

Please help. Also, is there any way I can use the `mpg_test` and `cyl_test` without `nrow(Values)` inside plot_ly

---

**script.r**

```
source('./r_files/flatten_HTML.r')

############### Library Declarations ###############
libraryRequireInstall("ggplot2");
libraryRequireInstall("plotly")
####################################################

################### Actual code ####################
Values <- data.frame(mpt_test, cyl_test)

p <- plot_ly(Values,
  x = ~mpt_test[1:nrow(Values), ],
  y = ~cyl_test[1:nrow(Values), ],
  name = "SF Zoo",
  type = "bar"
)

####################################################

############# Create and save widget ###############
#p = ggplotly(p);
internalSaveWidget(p, 'out.html');
####################################################
```

**capabilities.json**

```
{
  "dataRoles": [
    {
      "displayName": "Mileage Per Gallon",
      "kind": "GroupingOrMeasure",
      "name": "mpg_test"
    },
    {
      "displayName": "Cylinder Size",
      "kind": "GroupingOrMeasure",
      "name": "cyl_test"
    }
  ],
  "dataViewMappings": [
    { "conditions": [
                {
                    "mpg_test": {
                        "max": 1
                    },
                    "cyl_test": {
                        "max": 1
                    }
                }
            ],
      "scriptResult": {
        "dataInput": {
          "table": {
            "rows": {
              "select": [
                {
                  "for": {
                    "in": "mpg_test"
                  }
                },
                {
                  "for": {
                    "in": "cyl_test"
                  }
                }
              ],
              "dataReductionAlgorithm": {
                "top": {}
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "script": {
          "scriptProviderDefault": "R",
          "scriptOutputType": "html",
          "source": {
            "objectName": "rcv_script",
            "propertyName": "source"
          },
          "provider": {
            "objectName": "rcv_script",
            "propertyName": "provider"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "objects": {
    "rcv_script": {
      "properties": {
        "provider": {
          "type": {
            "text": true
          }
        },
        "source": {
          "type": {
            "scripting": {
              "source": true
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "suppressDefaultTitle": true
}
```

Comment: This should be working fine with both `ggplot` and `plotly`. I have tested both `mpg` data and some random data. Can you provide a reproducible example from a to z so we can pinpoint the problem?

Comment: @Majid: Thank you for trying.
I updated the question with my `script.r` and `capabilities.json`
Can you please try, not with the name `mpg` and `cyl`, instead try with different names.

Comment: @Majid: Can you please, provide your code where it worked.